# $p \leftrightarrow q \equiv (p \to q) \wedge (q \to p)$ Prove using conditional identities

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

**Q.** $p \longleftrightarrow q \equiv (p \to q) \wedge (q \to p)$

R.H.S:

$(p \to q) \wedge (q \to p)= (\neg p \vee q) \wedge (\neg q \vee p)$

Let $m = \neg p \vee q$

$= m \wedge (\neg q \vee p)$

$= (m \wedge\neg q) \vee (m \wedge p)$ ......using Distributive law

(-> Put value of $m$ back)

= $((\neg p \vee q) \wedge \neg q) \vee (\neg p \vee q) \wedge p)$

= ?

**I can't like this:**
$(\neg q \wedge \ q) \neg p) \vee (\neg p \wedge p) \vee q)$ Right?

Note: I was not able to write in correct mathematical form as I don't know.

Comment: I like the red symbol you used ;) if you sorround a line with the dollar sign $, it renders what is inside as mathematical notation. Then \wedge is ^, \vee is v, \rightarrow is -> and \iff is <->

Comment: @RSerrao, thanks, but which red symbol you are talking about?

Comment: the <->... i see it as a red sign

Comment: @RSerrao, OK :D I copy pasted the question from somewhere. that's why it has good mathematical arrows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that you can't do what you propose.  Associativity works only within the same connective.

From $$ ((-p \lor q) \land -q) \lor ((-p \lor q) \land p)$$

We get, using the distributive property twice, $$(\lnot p \land \lnot q)\lor(q\land \lnot q) \lor (\lnot p \land p) \lor (q \land p)$$

$$\equiv (\lnot p \land \lnot q) \lor (p \land q)$$

This is exactly how the biconditional $p\longleftrightarrow q$ is defined.  It means either  $(p\land q) \lor (\lnot p \land \lnot q)$

Comment: But I though biconditional is defined as `(p --> q) ^ (q <-- p)` so at the end this should have come.

Comment: Oh it does; $(p\iff q) \equiv (p\rightarrow q) \land (q\rightarrow p)$ that's what you proved!  But you can also see the equivalence between $p\longleftrightarrow q$ and $(\lnot p \land \lnot q) \lor (p\land q)$ using a truth table.

Comment: @TitanicLover You can't *prove* $(p\leftrightarrow q \equiv (p\to q)\wedge (q\to p)$ by *defining* $(p\leftrightarrow q \mathop{:=} (p\to q)\wedge (q\to p)$.  That's just going around in circles.  You have to start somewhere *else*; which amWhy does by saying that two predicates are biconditional *iff* they are either both true or both false.